# Simple ssh2_connect gives me supplied resource is not a valid SSH2 SFTP resource errror

Tags: php

in PHP:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($server, 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'password'); // connects GOOD !
ssh2_sftp_unlink ($connection , "/var/www/$db/url.txt");
ssh2_scp_recv($connection, "/var/www/url.txt", "/var/www/url.txt");
```

> PHP Warning:  ssh2_sftp_unlink(): supplied resource is not a valid
>   SSH2 SFTP resource  PHP Warning:  ssh2_scp_recv(): Unable to receive
>   remote file in

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation, you are missing the sftp resource object:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($server, 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', 'password');
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection); // <-- THis line
ssh2_sftp_unlink ($sftp, "/var/www/$db/url.txt");
```

Here is [the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp-unlink.php):

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

ssh2_sftp_unlink($sftp, '/home/username/stale_file');
?>
```

*Note:* with ssh2_scp_recv, you are trying to download the file that you have just deleted. Maybe you can reverse the order. Download then delete.